# Difference between hdfs movefromlocal and copyFromLocalFile

Tags: java, filesystems, hadoop, hdfs

I am using hadoop hdfs to store large data.
I need to first transfer files from local to hadoop. Now I am using copyFromLocalFile method, and set delete afet copy to true.

May I ask what's the difference between copy and move? Which one is more efficient and safe?

Thank you very much and have a great weekend:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them call the same method finally, so it shouldn't make any difference. Here is code for [FileSystem](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.22/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java).

It will get some time to get used to the code for Hadoop or in fact for any software, but it's better to get used to it. Documentation is sparse for most of the open source frameworks and so code is the ultimate source of truth.

Download the code using svn/git, set it up in Eclipse or NetBeans and browse through the code.